# jQuery - change value of Div ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<div id="something">
content
</div>
```

And I need change `something` to `somethingnew` by using jQuery, so:

```
<div id="somethingnew">
content
</div>
```

How can I do it? I've tried function `attr`, but it doesn't work.
Thanks for advices.

Comment: `attr()` should work fine, as well as `prop()`. Please show the code you tried, as if that didn't work then there must be an underlying issue elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This this:

```
$("#something").attr("id", "somethingnew");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$("#something").attr("id","somethingnew");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#something").attr("id", "somethingnew");` should work just fine